# Could the universe be a 4-ball?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, topology, spacetime-dimensions

I recently thought of the idea that the universe could be an infinite 4-ball. The Big Bang would be its centre, and time would be outward from its centre (one layer would be one point in time). I thought this made sense since one layer of a 4-ball would be three-dimensional, which is the way we observe one point in time, and the theory of relativity describes time as not separate from space.

For me, this also made sense since they say the expansion of the universe accelerates, which matches with the properties of a 4-ball, and it would as far as I know remove the need for dark energy, since the gravity would cancel out. It would also remove the need for an "origin" of the universe, since it would just go on forever in all directions.

However, my knowledge of physics is very limited as I am just a primary school student, so I have little way of knowing if this view would make any sense at all. Therefore I wonder whether and why I am (not) wrong.

Comment: Hi Masimatutu, It is excellent that you are having these idea's at such a young age, you will go very far with such characteristic. There has been a lot of research into this and the best approximation we have is that the universe is approximately flat as far as we know.

Comment: Welcome to SE. It is a cool thing that you think about these things. I think you have some confusion about what a 3-sphere is. It is 3-dimensional, as you correctly understand, but I think you are NOT 'picturing' a 3-sphere, you are picturing a 3-dimensional 'ball'... a sphere has no 'layers', and also no center, and no 'outwards from the center'. A sphere is the 'surface' of a four dimensional ball. Now, since you want to include time into these description, you are still missing one dimension, since we have 3 spatial dimensions already.

Comment: On the note of dark matter, when discussing the expansion of the universe etc. we would more talk about dark energy. As this seems to be the reason as to why the universe is undergoing a currently accelerated expansion

Comment: You're actually talking about a 3-ball. Each layer of the ball is a 3-sphere. This is a reasonable idea, since the curvature of an infinite n-sphere is zero, and our best measurements of the global spatial curvature of the universe indicate that it's *very* close to zero. However, your model doesn't quite match the observed expansion rate, which has changed over time. The acceleration in expansion is a relatively recent phenomenon, and currently the simplest way to model that acceleration is with dark energy.

Comment: @PM2Ring Each layer of a 3-ball is a 2-sphere, not a 3-sphere. Also, is an infinite sphere actually well-defined?

Comment: @Sandejo Oops! Thanks for that correction. I suppose an infinite radius sphere isn't exactly well-defined, but we can define it as the limit as the curvature approaches zero. FWIW, it can be useful to treat straight lines as circles of zero curvature, eg in [Descartes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem).

Comment: I see many people pointed out I was confusing 3-spheres with 4-balls. Thank you for the correction, I have edited the question now.